# I get IndexError when looping lines of a file

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, file-io

I'm still fairly new to Python and I just don't get what's wrong here.

I get an `IndexError: list index out of range` in the middle of reading lines from a CSV file. The file has ~135k lines of data. After the code has processed line 38.715 I receive aforementioned error for the code line with the `print` function. I don't get what is causing this, as there are no problems with any lines before that one, and the structure or type of the data doesn't change. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) in VMware btw.

Note: the `str(int(row[2]))` is just to remove preceding 0's so I can compare the string to another string afterwards.

This is my code:

```
import csv
with open('/home/joakim/Desktop/SomeFile.csv', 'r') as f_id:
    f_reader = csv.reader(f_id, delimiter=';')
    for row in f_reader:
        print ('C.id:', row[0], 'PR.id:', row[1], 'Id:', str(int(row[2])))
```

Can anyone point me in any direction?

Comment: I guess some line is malformed - there are no 3 csv columns , so when you try to access third column an Exception is raised. Can you verify how `row` object looks line in iteration when exception is raised?

Comment: I checked lines 38.715 and 38.716 in the file I'm reading from, and the data is of the same format with the same delimiter and all. Also I just exported the CSV file from an XLSX file, so I can't see how the data can be malformed.

I will try and print the whole row object before the other print I do, though.

Comment: Try adding `print(len(row))` to confirm this.

Comment: @MartinEvans or, `if len(row) < 3: print row`

Comment: @Łukasz R. Lol, I'm an idiot! :P Thanks for your answer, I just found the culprit. Apparantly when I copied the file from host OS to VMware, it didn't copy all the data in the file. And I was looking in the file located in the host OS for errors :P Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make. There are settings for file editors to use different colours depending upon where the file is in the system for just this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparantly when I copied the file from host OS to VMware, it didn't copy all the data in the file. I was mistakenly looking for errors in the file located in the host OS instead of the file I had copied to the guest OS.

So the answer is: I had to copy the file to the guest OS one more time and check that all the data was there.

Thanks for the comments - made me find the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, an empty value or NULL is present in any index of variable row.

You can use:

```
row[0] or ""
row[1] or ""
row[2] or ""
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, learning something new is always good :-)

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, the problem is due to a row that doesn't have all the elements that are requested to be printed.

In python it's common and often encouraged to use `try` and `except` blocks for error handling.

For example, in your case, the following could help you find the problematic row

```
import sys
...
    try:
        print(...,row[2])
    except IndexError:
        printf("Error: missing element(s) in row: ",row,file=sys.stderr)
        # sys.exit(2) # if you want to exit program with error
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer - I found out that the copy of the file in my VM was missing data, and I was looking for errors in the file in the host OS. That's why it made no sense to me :P